# EasyPeasyICS is not sending ics file with my email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

In codeigniter, working with phpMailer, I am trying to use EasyPeasyICS to help build an email with an ics file and this is a portion of my code:

```
    $invite = new EasyPeasyICS();
    $invite->addEvent(strtotime($appointment_data['start_datetime']),strtotime($appointment_data['end_datetime']),
        $service_data['name'],$message." ".$appointment_link,$appointment_link);
    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $mail->From = $company_settings['company_email'];
    $mail->FromName = $company_settings['company_name'];
    $mail->AddAddress($receiver_address); // "Name" argument crushes the phpmailer class.
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = $title;
    $mail->Body  =  $email_html;
    $mail->Ical = $invite->render(false);
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        throw new Exception('Email could not been sent. Mailer Error (Line ' 
                . __LINE__ . '): ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

So, what I get is my HTML email and no ICS file.  If I modify $mail->Ical = $invite->render(true) then the ics file downloads to me and I see the ICS file wrapped around my HTML as it is supposed to be and it looks great.  Why is it not sending out with the email?

Comment: Codeigniter has built in email library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: It looks like you've based your code on an old example, so make sure you're using an [up to date PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). There are some issues with ICS emails as gmail and outlook do not follow the standards. Check your received message structure contains an ical MIME part in the top-level multipart/alternative.

Comment: Thanks Sychro8.  What I found was that leaving out the AltBody was messing things up.  And it did not matter what text I used.  I just need to have it in the mix.  Then the ICS was produced with the email.  But, the HTML is partially stripped so, the MIME part is likely not being produced properly. I am using an older version of PHPMailer.  I will try updating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the latest version (5.2.22), you must set AltBody if you want to parse Ical. Because alternative (alt) message type is required to Ical to be loaded.

But if you specify Ical, your email WILL BE an event, and will be considered as it by email clients.